# Is it possible to put two div elements side-by-side without using CSS float?

Tags: html, css, layout

I keep finding that IE and Firefox do strange things to surprise me when I use CSS float to put two elements side-by-side on a page.

Is it possible to have two divs side by side on a web page without using CSS float?

```
<div id='div1'>
<p> div1 p1 </p>
<p> div1 p2 </p>
</div>
<div id='div2'>
<p> div2 p1 </p>
<p> div2 p2 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: In particular, I keep having layout issues with CSS float and borders.  In many cases, I want to have a border around a div, and the browser will draw the border thru a left-floating image!

Comment: You then need to add some padding to your DIV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with absolute positioning.

```
<div id="container">
<div id='div1'>
<p> div1 p1 </p>
<p> div1 p2 </p>
</div>
<div id='div2'>
<p> div2 p1 </p>
<p> div2 p2 </p>
</div>
```

And sample CSS.

```
#container {
position: relative;
width: 800px;
}
#div1, #div2 {
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
}
#div1 {
left: 0;
}
#div2 {
left: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

DIVs are block elements. You can make them inline be using `display:inline` or  `display:inline-block` or you can use absolute positioning

Answer (score 1):

Except for float, you can also give them: `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`, but that will probably give you other problems.

But remember, 'never leave a floated element uncleared!' If you remember that, your troubles will be few.

Comment: I have never been able to get `display:inline` this to work with divs. Can you provide an HTML to show how to do this?

Comment: Note that margins for top and bottom don't work on inline elements (that's one of those problems). The elements are indeed inline, like an image is inline with text. You can specify left and right margins, and padding on all sides as well. As you can see in the fiddle, I set the margins and padding on all sides, but the top margin is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than float, you can set their display to `display: inline;`, which will make them inline elements rather than block-level ones.

Comment: I have never been able to get this to work.  Can you provide an HTML to show how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
<div style="display:table">
  <div style="display:table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell">
       <p> div1 p1 </p>
       <p> div1 p2 </p>

    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell">
       <p> div1 p1 </p>
       <p> div1 p2 </p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: This is not working in lower version ie.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having troubles with borders and widths do this: make outer most div a wrapper (width/height only) then style accordingly on the inside. Only add padding to the elements on the inside.

Remember that border always takes away from your width. So if you have a 200px wide box and you want 2px border then your width is 196px.

`<div class="wrapper" style="height:200px">...do stuff here</div>`