# Can't place one div below another - they appear on top of each other now

Tags: css, html, position

I have 2 containers right now and I want 1 of these containers to be below the other. In each of these containers, I have 2 side by side div's courtesy of this post: [Is it possible to put two div elements side-by-side without using CSS float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448363/is-it-possible-to-put-two-div-elements-side-by-side-without-using-css-float)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="one">testing one</div>
    <div class="two">testing two</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="one">testing three</div>
    <div class="two">testing four</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zWk2y/14/

I want to one&two, three&four next to each other but one&two on top of three&four so it makes a 2x2 grid. But it keeps appearing on top of each other.

Thanks

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You have two elements with the "container" id.

Comment: Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zWk2y/9/

Comment: Note also that your CSS uses .container to select an ID. You must use #container instead. The CSS was not being applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/zWk2y/1/)**

HTML

```
<div id="container1">
  div class="one">testing one</div>
  <div class="two">testing two</div>
</div>
<div id="container2">
   <div class="one">testing three</div>
   <div class="two">testing four</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container1, #container2 {
    padding: 0 0 0 8%;
    width: 100%;
}
.one {
    width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.two {
    width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You are using the same id `container` for both div's. Id should be unique.

Comment: I fixed mine to use classes but never translated over to fiddle correctly. But thank you! This was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div class="container">` and apply the following CSS:

```css
.one {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.two {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pNpSB/3/).

Answer (score 0):

First you cant use id as repeating  can you please change it like this

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="one">testing one</div>
<div class="two">testing two</div>
</div>
<div class="containers">
<div class="one">testing three</div>
<div class="two">testing four</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
padding: 0 0 0 8%;
width: 100%;

}

.containers{
padding: 0 0 0 8%;
width: 100%;

}


.one {
width: 45%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
}

.two {
width: 45%;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I had used containers as a class in my code but didn't translate it over right

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues with your markup. See the below demo and code:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8SK3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container1">
    <div class="one">testing one</div>
    <div class="two">testing two</div>
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <div class="one">testing three</div>
    <div class="two">testing four</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container1 {
background-color:yellow;
}
#container2
{
    background-color:orange;
}
.one,.two
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
    border:1px solid;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the colors! That illustrated it more correctly. But this didn't work ... the .one, .two needed to have a position: relative on it. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    padding: 0 0 0 8%;
    width: 100%; 
}
.one {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
.two {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
.container {
    padding: 0 0 0 8%;
}
.inner {
    float:left;
    width:45%;
}

<div  class="container">
    <div class="inner">testing one</div>
    <div class="inner">testing two</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">testing three</div>
    <div class="inner">testing four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use floats, you can do it this way.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="one">three</div>
   <div class="two">four</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    padding: 0 0 0 8%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.one {
    width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
}
.two {
   width: 45%;
   position: relative;
   float:left;
}
```

You can't have two elements with the same id.  Replaced `<div id="container">` with 
`<div class="container">`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hVgQv/